# Spot/div correlation for autocalls

Tags: dividends

I cannot find much litterature on the effect of the spot/div correlation or the shape of the spot/div cross gamma concerning the autocallable structures.
In a general way, could someone present an intuitive reasoning, from the point of view of an autocall seller, of the expected impacts wrt to this parameter ?
Thank you for your answer